# Cant connect to docker containers running on Photon OS 4.0 Linux server

Tags: docker

We have a Linux server that ran Photon OS 3.0 and hosted multiple docker containers. Ip tables were enforced. On upgrading to Photon OS 4.0, we cant seem to connect to the docker containers running on this server via the internet.

Our first step was to check if there was anything wrong with the container and the image. We were able to recreate this container in a test server running Photon OS 3.0 and it ran without any issues.

Next we looked at the ip tables and it seems to look correct.

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 122 packets, 13607 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1       26  2515 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2     3446  524K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3        2   104 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
4      171 20326 LIGHTWAVE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1      294 15852 DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2      294 15852 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
4        0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
5        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
6        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
7        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      br-54495f9a6e79  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
8      270 14040 DOCKER     all  --  *      br-54495f9a6e79  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
9       24  1812 ACCEPT     all  --  br-54495f9a6e79 !br-54495f9a6e79  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
10       0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br-54495f9a6e79 br-54495f9a6e79  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
11       0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      br-1fce5c4b82f2  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
12       0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      br-1fce5c4b82f2  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
13       0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br-1fce5c4b82f2 !br-1fce5c4b82f2  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
14       0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br-1fce5c4b82f2 br-1fce5c4b82f2  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1     2285  322K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER (3 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1       90  4680 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-54495f9a6e79 br-54495f9a6e79  0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:443
2      105  5460 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-54495f9a6e79 br-54495f9a6e79  0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:80

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2       24  1812 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  br-54495f9a6e79 !br-54495f9a6e79  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3        0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  br-1fce5c4b82f2 !br-1fce5c4b82f2  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
4      294 15852 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (3 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      br-54495f9a6e79  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      br-1fce5c4b82f2  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
4       24  1812 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1      294 15852 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain LIGHTWAVE (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1      171 20326 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

We verified the tls versions and the Photon os 4.0 has the following

```
SSLv3
TLSv1
TLSv1.2
TLSv1.3
```

and PhotonOS 3.0 has the following

```
SSLv3
TLSv1.2
```

the docker compose file i am using is as follows

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  maximohomepage.dev:
    image: maximohomepage:development
    container_name: maximohomepage-dev
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=<password>
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=webportal.pfx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - default
networks:
   default:
     external:
       name: maximohomepage
```

Inspecting the docker network , this is what we see.

```
[
    {
        "Name": "maximohomepage",
        "Id": "54495f9a6e79b0f62e622c8138dbfa6d1e4de2a0faa5cb6afb637c54b8a6385e",
        "Created": "2021-08-05T15:05:23.996371864-06:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "54f7ca97ed2da87db565c6a355a3b6edd5da8a86134558d9e15cc470e017b17d": {
                "Name": "maximohomepage-dev",
                "EndpointID": "60c035267b76134f578f0e72e7178663261ce3e43c73003508d9d8464a7e0823",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

I was wondering if anyone could tell me what's the next thing i should look for? I am not very experienced on the server side so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you